# FindGameObject.WithTag Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

По команде  GameObject FindWithTag(string tag); возвращает один активный объект с тэгом. А мне бы все объекты c этим тэгом запихнуть в Array. Как это возможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы будете смеяться, но в списке методов `GameObject` сразу над методом [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) написан метод [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html), который возвращает список активных *GameObject*'ов с тегом `tag`. Возвращает пустой список, если не найдено ни одного *GameObject*'а.

Пример:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject respawnPrefab;
    public GameObject[] respawns;
    void Start() {
        if (respawns == null)
            respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Respawn");

        foreach (GameObject respawn in respawns) {
            Instantiate(respawnPrefab, respawn.transform.position, respawn.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```